# Transparent border not working with linear gradient

Tags: html, css, gradient, linear-gradients

```css
.box:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: -1px;
    right: -5px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-bottom: 23px solid #ff0e1f;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  
}
.box:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
  left: -5px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 23px solid #ff0e1f;
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
}
.box {
  margin-left: 20px;  
  position: relative;
    background-image: linear-gradient(135deg,rgb(131,0,255) 14%,rgb(234,48,255) 100%);
    padding: 3px 13px;
    line-height: 16px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.box>a {
    color: #fff!important;
  background-image: linear-gradient(135deg,rgb(131,0,255) 14%,rgb(234,48,255) 100%);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 13px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: poppins;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/">Esports is the best game</a></div>
```

I want to add gradient to the whole part which is showing in red color. But I am not finding any way to do this. Is there anyone who can fix this?I have tried a lot of different codes but nothing is working for me.

If I add gradient color to the red part then transparent border will not work. Can I fix this? Or is there any other code instead of div through which I can do the thing which I want.

Here is my sample code:

```
    <div class="box">
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/">Esports is the best game</a></div>


.box:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: -1px;
    right: -5px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-bottom: 23px solid #ff0e1f;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  
}
.box:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
  left: -5px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 23px solid #ff0e1f;
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
}
.box {
  margin-left: 20px;  
  position: relative;
    background-image: linear-gradient(135deg,rgb(131,0,255) 14%,rgb(234,48,255) 100%);
    padding: 3px 13px;
    line-height: 16px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.box>a {
    color: #fff!important;
  background-image: linear-gradient(135deg,rgb(131,0,255) 14%,rgb(234,48,255) 100%);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 13px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: poppins;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: What gradient do you want in those triangular bits? Is it just an extension of the linear-gradient of the main bi (that purple color)?

Comment: Have you investigated clip path?

Comment: Oh yeah. My issue has fixed after using clip path. Thanks for your precious time.

Comment: If you put your solution into an answer it could help someone else in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the correct HTML and CSS code:

```css
.box {
  background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, rgb(131, 0, 255) 14%, rgb(234, 48, 255) 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(calc(0% + 12px) 0%, 100% 0%, calc(100% - 12px) 100%, 0% 100%);
  padding: 3px 13px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.a {
  color: #fff!important;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: poppins;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <a href="https://www.youtube.com/" class="a">Tournaments</a>
</div>
```